# UWP Launcher.LaunchFileAsync command is working in debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: c#, uwp

We have a UWP app in c# which will write data to a file and then it will open the same file to view/edit. I am using Launcher.LaunchFileAsync command to launch the file. It works fine in debug mode but its now launching the file in release mode.

```
    StorageFile launchFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(@"xxx\zzz-files\" + fileName);
    Log.Debug("UWP launch default app: " + launchFile.Path);
    Log.Debug("UWP launch default app: " + launchFile.Name);
    try
    {
       var success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(launchFile);
       Log.Debug("UWP launch default app success: " + success);
    }
```

Log file shows the correct file path and filename. I could open the file from file explorer. Success is always "false". There are no error messages in the log or in console.

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing that on UI thread? because you should: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28788642/7034621

Comment: The code works well in my side both release and debug mode, could you provide a simple sample that can reproduce it?